# Sonata media gallery

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, symfony-sonata, sonata-media-bundle

I try to make a web site with Symfony. So I installed SonataAdminBundle and SonataMediaBundle.

And I have a question about Sonata media.
I created a gallery with a lots of image media in it and I don't know how I can access it from my Controller.

*How can I get my media (image) contained in my gallery for show them in my template?*

thx for help !

EDIT:
I solved my problem !

So in my template I do:

```
{% for img in MyEntity.gallery.galleryHasMedias %}
    <img src={% path img.media, 'reference'%}>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Show a bit of you're code or investigation.

Answer (score 0):

Usually Gallery or Media entity are related to other entities and we retrieve them from their relation. 
e.g. from owner of a gallery or related medias to a product. after fetching pass media object(image in this case) to template(twig or php) and use [sonata media helpers](http://sonata-project.org/bundles/media/2-2/doc/reference/helpers.html) to display them.